# What is the R code for estimating copula parameters of BB1 with dim=2? And what's the code for gof test of BB1?

Tags: finance-mathematics, econometrics, statistical-finance, copula, financial-engineering

Kindly assist with R code for BB1 copula. Text books and research articles provide codes for clayton, gumbel, frank, normal and t copulas.  However, I can't find code for BB1, the copula family defined in `H. Joe: Multivariate Models and Multivariate Dependence Concepts, Chapman & Hall, 1997, p. 150`

For example, this is the code I found:

```
gf <- gofCopula(normalCopula(dim = 2), as.matrix(mydata), N = 50). ## I obtained results here
```

But I get an error when I run:

```
gfBB1 <- gofCopula(BB1Copula(dim = 2), as.matrix(mydata), N = 50)
```

> Error in BB1Copula(dim = 2) : unused argument (dim = 2)

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out what the code is. Note that theta and delta come from the copula selected for you through the BiCopSelect() command.

```
theta <- selectedCopula$par
delta <- selectedCopula$par2

gfBB1 <- gofCopula(BB1Copula(c(theta, delta)), as.matrix(mydata), N = 50)
```